# angular2 - tabs content load it from local json file

Tags: json, angular, tabs

I am working on angular 2 Tabs component.

Currently i am following below Plunker example
[Angular 2 Tabs](https://plnkr.co/edit/qEp5ymXWJVtkuc0fclUE?p=preview)

I need to make Tabs dynamic by reading the Local JSON file.

My JSON

```
    [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "General",
    "content": [
      {
        "header": "Basic Information",
        "contents": [
          {
            "label": "Report goes here"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Additional info",
    "content": [
      {
        "header": " Information",
        "contents": [
          {
            "label": "Report goes here"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Service.ts

```
    export class DashboardService{

    private _url: string = "assets/sample.json";

    constructor( private _http: Http){}

      getRecords(){
          return this._http.get(this._url)
          .map((response:Response) => response.json())
          .catch(this._errorHandler);
      }

      _errorHandler(error: Response){
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
      }

}
```

Component.ts

```
    export class DynamicTabsComponent implements OnInit{

    records = [];
    errorMsg: string;

    constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this._dashboardService.getRecords()
        .subscribe(
        resGetRecords => this.records = resGetRecords,
        resRecordsError => this.errorMsg = resRecordsError
        );
    }

}
```

Now how to read it in the component file.

here in **tab** link, i am expecting is

- Additional info
- General

Description required with header and label.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do an *ngFor on your json to display the tabs:

```
<tabs>
   <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" tabTitle="{{tab.name}}">
     <div>{{tab.content[0].header}}</div>
     <div>{{tab.content[0].contents[0].label}}</div>
   </tab>
</tabs>
```

You declare your json into the component or import it from outside:

```
class App {

tabs =  [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "General",
    "content": [
      {
        "header": "Basic Information",
        "contents": [
          {
            "label": "Report goes here"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Additional info",
    "content": [
      {
        "header": " Information",
        "contents": [
          {
            "label": "Report goes here"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

}
```

Working fork of your plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Eip7SuAXUYekTSRI9dq?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Buddy. It helped me lot

Answer (score 1):

If it's a local JSON file, why are you making http calls ?

To read a JSON file, simply do

```
let jsonFile = require('relative/path/to/json/file.json')
```

And it should load your JSON file.